# Where am I supposed to define a constraint for routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the rails guides for advanced constraints [Advanced Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints). Here is the code:

```
class BlacklistConstraint
  def initialize
    @ips = Blacklist.retrieve_ips
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '*path', to: 'blacklist#index',
    constraints: BlacklistConstraint.new
end
```

The guides fail to mention where the `BlacklistConstraint` is supposed to be defined or whether it follows naming conventions. I've tried to follow this example for my own use but I keep getting an `UninitialiezedConstantError: Can someone help me out? So far I;ve defined my constraint class in the 1`routes.rb`file itself and in the`lib` directory. Both methods did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expected place for this class would be **lib/constraints**.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints-label-Dynamic+request+matching

**Update:**
Based on the helpful comments, I'll try to make this a complete answer.

According to the docs your constraint class should be placed under `lib/constraints`, but since the `lib` directory is not eager loaded by rails you can enable it by adding this line to `config/application.rb`

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Now rails will try to load the `lib/constraints/blacklist_constraint.rb` file and would expect it to be correctly namespaced, so wrap that class in a Module (which also makes it cleaner because you might have more constraints in the future)

```
module Constraints
  class BlacklistConstraint
    def initialize
      @ips = Blacklist.retrieve_ips
    end

    def matches?(request)
      @ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
    end
  end
end
```

and reference `Constraints::BlacklistConstraint` in `routes.rb`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but for some reason this didn't work for me. I had to require the file path in my `application.rb`.

Comment: You have to turn on autoloading/eagerloading the files from the `lib` folder. http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/08/29/rails-5-disables-autoloading-after-booting-the-app-in-production.html

Comment: But this constraint's `initialize' is run while booting, so adding additional _IPs_ would require the application to be restarted